# How to encode string using .net libs

Tags: c#, encoding, urlencode

I need to encode string like this using standard libs:
 "`{some-string.for#encode}`" to "`%7bsome%2dstring%2efor%23encode%7d"`

```
HttpUtility.UrlDecode("{some-string.for#encode}")
```

Does not work as expected and returns:

> "%7bsome-string.for%23encode%7d"

Comment: well: *why* do you need those other characters encoded? things like `-` and `.` are *not* reserved, so there should be no need to %-encode them. If you're already playing off-spec, why not encode *every* character?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that `-` and `.` aren't being encoded is that [section 2.3 of rfc3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.3) *explicitly permits* them as "unreserved" characters. As such, no *standards compliant* percent-encoder will *do* this, for exactly the same reason that they don't encode "some" (that is *also* part of section 2.3, via the label `ALPHA`).

So: if you aren't going to be following the spec, you'll have to write the encoder yourself.